# Random redirects to a 404 for a .html website

Tags: apache-2.2

I've got about 25 servers running hundreds of websites behind a load balancer. They're all using Apache/2.2.15 on CentOS 6.6. There is one site that is having random 301s which are redirecting to a https version of another site. I've gone through the configurations and rsync -azvp --delete'd all the conf.d directories but still have this really weird error. I'd love some ideas of where to look to debug this really strange error.

I don't see the 303 redirects in the apache log but I see the 404 errors in the ssl version of another website and I do see the redirects in the Chrome developer console.

/var/log/subdomain-website-access_log:1.1.1.1 - - [04/Aug/2015:09:33:44 -0700] "GET /images/header.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 313

When I put http://www.website.com/images/header.jpg into the URL of the browser it redirects to the 404 as well.

Here's the configuration for the site that has the random redirects

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.website.com
    ServerAlias website.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@website.com
    DocumentRoot /home/website.com/www
    ErrorLog /var/log/website.com-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/website.com-access_log combined
    LogLevel error

    <Directory "/">
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/website.com/www">
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's the configuration for the site that gets them.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName subdomain.website.com
        Redirect permanent / https://subdomain.website.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName noc@website.com
    DocumentRoot /home/subdomain/www
    ServerName subdomain.website.com

    ErrorLog "/var/log/subdomain-website-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/subdomain-website-access_log" common
    LogLevel error

    # Turn on Expires and set default to 0
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault A0

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS"
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/httpd/certs/website.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/httpd/certs/website.key"
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    <Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +ExecCGI +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/subdomain/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +ExecCGI +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does all of the backends host all of the sites? Or does the loadbalancer have to figure out which site is being requested in order to direct the request to the proper backend? The most likely source of apparent random behavior in a setup like yours would be that one of the backends is returning incorrect result, and from the user's point of view the backend is chosen at random by the loadbalancer.

Comment: All the backends host all of the sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem caused by a wildcard in a third website configuration.

```
ServerAlias *
```

That was making all the other sites act funny. Any chance you've got a wildcard in there?

Comment: Looks like that was it. I removed it and put all the separate domains in the config as ServerAliases and rebooted the load balancer and just sent 10000 requests through with 100% sucess rate.